# not able to change the color of the link using :link selector

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of the link using `:link` selector, but the browser doesn't seem to change the color. what's wrong?

```css
a:link{
    color:rgb(251, 255, 0);
    
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>

    <a href="https://www.google.com">click to go to google</a>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The :link selector styles links to pages you have not visited yet, have you factored that in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, you do not see the color because you probably already visited the link, so the selector matches `:visited`.

See this example taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp):

```css
a:link {
  color: red;
}

a:visited {
  color: green;
}

a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webpage</title>
    </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<body>

    <a href="https://www.google.com">click to go to google</a>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is because you already visited that URL, try to open it in incognito mode and you will see it red

Comment: I was using chrome browser to test the output, i ran in firefox recently and it worked fine. thanks for the help :)

Comment: does not depends from the browser vendor, but from the fact that the browser keep in its navigation data the link you visited, hence changing the CSS color. Flush the navigation data or open an incognito mode to reset the visited links

Comment: thanks for letting me know :) I thought i was using an older version of chrome. I changed the link value and it works fine! btw how to flush the navigation data?

Comment: In parameter -> flush navigation data

Answer (score 1):

The `:link` selector is used to style links that have *not* yet been visited/clicked.

The link started yellow, I clicked it and it went back to default colour. It seems to be working as expected? What behaviour are you after?

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. Link color should be yellow (not visited) but it doesn't seem to work. i refreshed the page and tried again, still no result

Comment: Try following this to [unvisit the link](https://superuser.com/questions/634824/how-to-unvisit-links-in-chrome/634827), since it will still be "visited" even after a refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) i changed the value of the link and it worked fine.